# How to make an image appear when a letter is input?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Say I wanted to make an image appear by inputting a letter. I press the letter a, click the button and an image would appear. But somehow, I failed to do this since I only want to use a switch statement. Here's a code I tried to do:

```
 <input type="text" id="abc">
 <button onclick="myFunction()"> </button>
 <br>
 <img src="" id="image">

 <script>
  var x = document.getElementById('abc').value;

  function myFunction() {
   switch (x) {
    case x = a:
     document.getElementById('image').src = "alligator.jpg";
    break;
    case x = b:
     document.getElementById('image').src = "baseball.jpg";
    break;
    default:
     window.alert('No input');
    break;
   }
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not quoting your strings, you don't need to do "x = a", it can just be the letter, and you are not getting an updated input value on function call.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('abc').value;
    switch (x) {
        case 'a':
            document.getElementById('image').src = "https://picsum.photos/id/1003/100/100";
            break;
        case 'b':
            document.getElementById('image').src = "https://picsum.photos/id/1020/100/100";
            break;
        default:
            window.alert('No input');
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="abc">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>
<br>
<img src="" id="image">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `x` out of the function so it is not getting updated value.
You need to put `x` inside `myFunction`, so that it will get updated value every time: Also you need string for `switch` statement.

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('abc').value;
  switch (x) {
    case x = 'a':
      document.getElementById('image').src = "https://9b16f79ca967fd0708d1-2713572fef44aa49ec323e813b06d2d9.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/1140x_a10-7_cTC/20190607MMSAlligator1-1569956549.jpg";
      break;
    case x = 'b':
      document.getElementById('image').src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Heyward_lines_into_double_play_%2828356212176%29.jpg";
      break;
    default:
      window.alert('No input');
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="abc">
<button onclick="myFunction()">click </button>
<br>
<img src="" id="image">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `x` inside function and case should have `"a"` & `"b"`, instead of those expresssion. Below snippet works:

```html
<input type="text" id="abc">
 <button onclick="myFunction()"> </button>
 <br>
 <img src="" id="image">

 <script>
  
  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('abc').value;
  
  switch (x) {
    case "a":
     document.getElementById('image').src = "alligator.jpg";
    break;
    case "b":
     document.getElementById('image').src = "baseball.jpg";
    break;
    default:
     window.alert('No input');
    break;
   }
  }
 </script>
```